# Devise, create a user that belongs to company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, slim-lang

I want to create a user with Devise, that have a belongs_to association.

What is missing? What needs to create a user that belongs to a company from a select list?

my form have this:

```
.siimple-form-field
        = f.label :name, class: "siimple-label"
        br
        = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "siimple-input siimple-input--fluid siimple--height-50"
      .siimple-form-field
        label.siimple-label
          | Select an option:
        = f.fields_for :company_attributes do |b|
          = b.select :company, Company.all.collect{|p| [p.name, p]}, {}, class: "siimple-select siimple-select--fluid"
```

the form shows ok, so when i try to submit, it says:

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:

    Company must exist
```

Also my **RegistrationsController** have:

```
def create
  super
end


def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :bank])
end
```

Comment: I am not easy with HAML but you use `fields_for` which is a way of getting fields belonging to another model. I am not sure you can (easily) do that with Devise. The only fields that you should query are the fields of your Devise model. If your Devise model User is a child of Company, just ask for the `company_id` field which should anyway be one of your User Devise model field. (you can make it nicer by showing the name of the company instead with a select helper)

Comment: (I am considering that Companies you want to add a user to already exist. If you want to create the Company and the User alltogether this is another story)

Comment: the company already exists, i have a select list for select the company where must belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!**

First them all, the registration controller was not **overriden** in the **routes** files, just got this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    # something missing no?

  }
```

**Fixed it with**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'

  }
```

*Then, just do common things like add something like this to the **controller**:*

```
def create
  params[:user][:company] = Company.find(params[:user][:company_id])
  super
end
```

*And add the missing permission to* **`configure_sign_up_params`**

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :company_id, :company])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that the company parameters are not being permitted (which means the company gets set to `nil`, hence the `Company must exist` error).

You have to override Devise's `resource_params` method to add your `company_id` attribute. Try putting this in your Registrations controller:

```
 def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_attribute_foo, :user_attribute_bar, :company_id)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your column name is company_id and you are using company in the form. Try by changing it and permit this parameter.